# Index and match to check data and provide exception results

Tags: excel, indexing, match

Need help in this

Currently i am using index and match in excel but however i am unable to get the result tt i want.. what i need is

data to check with item master whether all 3 (article, color code and size) matches and if it doesnt match, which of the field is wrong. (eg: wrong color code, wrong size or article dont exist)

```
Article       Color Code    Size

2-50150151         17        36
2-70680044         21        34
4-42110001          2        38
2-50660147          6         S
2-50660147          6         M
```

Above is my item master

---

Data to check

```
Article       Color Code    Size

2-50660147         6         M
2-50660147         8         M
```

Example case: 1

Checking first row of data check

Article number:    2-50660147

Color code:            6

Size:               M

Result: "Wrong size"

But however, it returns as wrong size as it only reads the first time the article number appear in the item master and does not recognize the second time the article number appears with the correct color and size.

Is there any way i can solve this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: what formula you're using?

Comment: =IF(INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet1!Q13)=Sheet1!D13,IF(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,Q13)=E13,IF(INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,Q13)=F13,"No Exception","Wrong Size"),"Wrong Colour"),"Wrong art")

Comment: "But however, it returns as wrong size as it only reads the first time the article number appear in the item master and does not recognize the second time the article number appears with the correct color and size."

**So basically how do you want to do the check? Can you please elaborate on this?**

Comment: what if the details in record are matching exactly with some other record?

Comment: i wan the check being able to check all the values in the items master with the same article number

Comment: okay, let me re-phrase. You want to check if any of the records in Article Master matched the check record or not? If yes, How would you rate the records as "No Exception | Wrong Color | Wrong Art " ... please explain... I don't seem to be very clear with your point.

Comment: eh ok.. i explain the scenario.. i have two files.. one is item master.. which is i created... den a data file sent to me.. what i need to do is to do a check on the data file that was sent to me.. if the articles details exist in the item master. for eg.. if the details in the data file match exactly the same as the item master then it will revert as no exception. if the size is different den it will reflect with wrong size. i think it is a bit hard to explain this way... is there any way i can attached my excel sheet here?

Comment: well, yes. you can create a google spreadsheet and share the link!

Comment: here's the link.. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqSz-lYotfpQdEQ2aDhCQkZ1UnJYd09KSUZVMms3ZHc&usp=sharing

Comment: cool, enable the rights to comment and edit so that we can do the required modifications then and there

Comment: the rights are enable

Comment: it's still in view only mode. Change the sharing mode to View and Edit.

Comment: u try again.. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqSz-lYotfpQdEQ2aDhCQkZ1UnJYd09KSUZVMms3ZHc&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I think Google Docs is still poor at evaluating complex formulas. My this answer is based on the assumption that, if any of the matching record is available in Master Table matching to search record, it should say "Yes" otherwise it should say "No". Correct me if I'm wrong.

try this formula if what I assumed above is okay.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$6=I2)*--($B$1:$B$6=J2)*--($C$1:$C$6=K2))=1,"Match Found!","Not Found!")
```

Change the range as per your data.

Comment: eh. becos i need to find out what is the exception, for eg.. wrong article number.. or wrong size for tt article or wrong color for tt article

Comment: okay, this is where I want the clarification. Suppose in Master Table Record1 contains entries: **" 2-50660147 | 6 | S "** and Record2 contains entries: **" 2-50660147 | 6 |  M "**. Now if I want to search for a record with entries:  **" 2-50660147 | 6 | M "** then, as per your concern, it will check the first record in master and will say "Wrong Size", then why will check the second record again where all the values of entry are matching? How do you want to check it?? I'm just not getting this point.

Comment: the formula tat is being used now only reflects the first time "2-50660147' appear and does not read the record 2...  this is a simplified sample.. becos i got a whole list of article number thats need to be checked with the item master.. and inside the item master.. i have like 1 article with many different color and sizes..  i not sure if u get my explanation

Comment: You're absolutely right! I really didn't. What I'm trying to clarify is, If Record one in Master doesn't match with search record but it matched with the second one in Master what should it do? It's okay that it will check record one and result as "wrong size" when it match with first record but, what if the next record is natching completely??

Comment: ok.. if the record 2 is match exactly den it will return a no exception msg

Comment: sorry dear friend... may be I'm not making sense. I'm out :)